# Alternative to Copy and Paste values based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out a efficient alternative to copy and paste vals based on a criteria. For example if column b contain costs, I want the 2nd tab to contain all data where costs are absent in column b.

Currently I have sheets("sh2").range("a1:k50000").value=sheets("sh1").range("a1:k50000").value

and then I delete all rows (using a for selection loop) in sh2 where costs are populated. However with large data sets deleting 1000s of rows can be a lengthy process.

Comment: Why are you using VBA instead of VLookUp?

Comment: If I was to use lookups by adding IDs in the 1st column, not only would that be extremely lengthy in that there are 15 columns  but there is still the requirement to delete rows with blank costs in column b

Answer (score 0):

You could use Excel's built in filtering to remove blanks before copying.  It would look something like this:

```
sheets("sh1").range("a1:k50000").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
sheets("sh1").Range("$a$1:$k$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
sheets("sh1").Range("$a$1:$k$50000").Copy
sheets("sh2").Range("$a$1").PasteSpecial
```

The Criteria1:="=" is the expression for blanks. "Field:=2" is Column 2/B to check for blanks. The key here is that the Copy command includes just the filtered cells so you will be pasting just the filtered data.

Also, if you do not have a header row in Range("$a$1:$k$50000") you may need to add one to get reliable results.